# 403 for ajax POST requests in Chrome on Windows 11 but not Windows 10

Tags: ajax, apache, http-status-code-403

I have a local network non-public server used to test applications that need to be deployed in http.

My work recently replaced my Windows 10 desktop with a Windows 11 machine.

Since then, when I try to run any ajax POST requests on the http test server in Chrome, I get a 403 error. The same exact same application at the exact same url will run fine and as expected on my old Windows 10 machine. Even in the same version of Chrome: Version 120.0.6099.71 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Ajax GET requests run fine with no 403 errors. Google search said probably something wrong with the preflight (since post has it but get doesn't), but the apache config on the server already looks like the answers I'm seeing for how to make sure that's right.

Example jquery code from postTest.html:

```
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://test.mysite.com/willItPost.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {anyVariableName: 'any old value'},

           success: function(data) {
              console.log('ajax request succeeded');
              console.log(data);
          },
          error: function() {
              console.log('ajax request failed');
            }
        });
```

Example php code of willItPost.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['anyVariableName'])){
    $message = 'anyVariableName exists as a post value.';
} else {
    $message = 'anyVariableName does not exist as a post value.';
}
$return = array('status' => $message);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

When I try to run the ajax, this shows up in the Chrome console:
`http://test.mysite.com/willItPost.php 403 (Forbidden)`

This happens even when I chmod the file to 777, so it does not seem to be a linux user permissions issue.

When I try to run the php page in the browser itself (not an ajax request), it returns this, as it should:

```
{
    "status": "anyVariableName does not exist as a post value."
}
```

When I look in the network tab of the console, I see this in the headers section (Note, I find it strange that I'm seeing "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" when the request is same origin, but maybe this is normal):

```
-----GENERAL-----
Request URL: http://test.mysite.com/willItPost.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: [redacted]
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
-----RESPONSE-----
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Security-Policy, Location
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 228
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2023 19:20:59 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
-----REQUEST-----
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 25574
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: test.mysite.com
Origin: http://test.mysite.com
Referer: http://test.mysite.com/postTest.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I am not a server admin, but I did find the apache config file, and this is the section for the root folder (as I said before, it already looks like all of the apache config answers I've seen for how to get rid of 403 errors, and basically just matches what is seen in the headers of the response above):

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

As a last note, there is no .htaccess file, so there's nothing there that could be interfering with the basic apache config.

As described above, after examining the headers and the apache config and not finding anything out of the ordinary, I'm a bit at a loss.

The only other thing I can think of is that maybe it has to do with improper configuration of my new local machine. Would that be possible? Network settings? DNS? How would I test that?